# React native : Can I run the assembleDebug APK in another network?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

Using React native **0.56.0** and React native navigation **v2**, generated debug APK does not run on another network, it shows a development server not connected bug on the screen. how can I run app-debug.apk in another network without development server? seen many answers, all are said to create release/unsigned APK.

Is it need to create Keystore to run for another network?
I will not distribute to play store, so I think no need to generate **signed APK**.

**Note** : can't open the app without `npm start`. npm start does bundle. how can I solve it?

created APK by following steps:

1. bundle the app

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

2. create debug APK:

`cd ./android && ./gradlew app:assembleDebug` // does not runs on another network

3. create release APK:

`cd ./android && ./gradlew app:assembleRelease` // app not installed

4. after run `npm start` from the project root and reload app runs fine

Comment: which URL are you using to connect?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko - URL? , did not get!

Comment: For this, you need to create signed APK. For generating signed APK you can follow this: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to distribute a debug APK ?

By default, React Native doesn't bundle the JS when building in debug, so the debug APK is an empty shell. 
Debug is for developers, it is expected to run locally on your computer, and JS bundle is NOT in the APK, but dynamically served by ReactNative bundler (Metro), which provides hot reload, debug menu, red box for errors, and all features we love...

Have a look at the build.gradle file in your app folder, there are lots of comments there that give a hint on how you can change this behaviour, read the comments below the line  `project.ext.react= [` . For example,

```
*   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
*   bundleInDebug: false,`
```

But, once again, why would you want to do that ?... isn't release good enough ? If it's not, you can create other variants of build... (alpha, beta, whatever you need)

Comment: every new implementation we need to pass an APK to testing team, is this good to  share `app-release.apk` all time?, my friends says release APK done while update to playstore only.

Comment: Thats maybe why you should have other variants of your build. Debug for dev, Alpha for testing, Release for Production / appstore (for example, that what we use...). You can have several configurations, but it requires to go a little deeper in your app/build.gradle.

Comment: Changed to true but still shows red screen "server not connected" in the mobile.

Comment: again: WHY change the debug config for a release build when debug is intended for... DEBUG purposes ?? You really should create another config instead! Still, if you want to break everything: have a look at `android > buildTypes > debug > debuggable true` in your `app/build.gradle`,   change it to false

Answer (score -2):

Generate Signed Apk .its work all

Comment: could you explain more?

Comment: Goto Tab bar android .after click Build button  .next see drop down list is showing  Generate Signed Apk .after  click create new  set key store  path any folder finish all after u getting signed apk

Comment: From android studio?, how can copy react project to android studio?

Comment: I am not going to distribute  to play store then why we need signed APK?